# Preventing a shell script from exiting with Control C

Tags: bash, shell

so I am trying to create a script which gives the user some options to do things, one of that option is to exit the script. However, I want to prevent the user from exiting the script using `Control c` so that the only way to exit is to select the right option. Is it possible to make the script so that when the user hits `control c`, the program will not exit, but rather it would `echo` something like `"enter 0 to exit"`?

```
#!/bin/bash
# Acts as a simple administration menu

OPTION=0

echo "-----------------Admin Menu-------------------"   
echo "Please select one of the following options:   "
echo ""
echo "1 - Run top."
echo "2 - Show system uptime."
echo "3 - Show logged in users."
echo "4 - Exit Menu."
echo "5 - Reprint this menu."
echo "----------------------------------------------"
echo "Please choose an option (5 to reprint menu):"
read OPTION

while [ "$OPTION" -ne 4 ]
do
    if [ "$OPTION" -eq 1 ]; then
        clear
        top -n1
    elif [ "$OPTION" -eq 2 ]; then
        clear
        uptime
    elif [ "$OPTION" -eq 3 ]; then
        clear
        who
    elif [ "$OPTION" -eq 4 ]; then
        clear
        OPTION=4
    elif [ "$OPTION" -eq 5 ]; then
        clear
        echo "------------COSC 2306 Admin Menu--------------"   
        echo "Please select one of the following options:   "
        echo ""
        echo "1 - Run top."
        echo "2 - Show system uptime."
        echo "3 - Show logged in users."
        echo "4 - Exit Menu."
        echo "5 - Reprint this menu."
        echo "----------------------------------------------"

    else
        clear
        echo "ERROR: Incorrect Input."
    fi
    echo "Please choose an option (5 to reprint menu):"
    read OPTION
done
clear
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `trap` built-in to catch `SIGINT` ( `ctrl` + `C` generates the signal `SIGINT`)  and print your message:

```
trap 'echo "enter 0 to exit"' SIGINT
```

Similarly you can catch other signals too. To get the list of signals use `kill -l`.

Comment: ok, but how would i add that to my code? i added my code to the question.

Comment: Use that as the first line e.g. as next line to the `#!/bin/bash` line. In your code, you can use it right before `OPTION=0` line.

Comment: so like #! trap 'echo "enter 0 to exit"' SIGINT

Comment: Not with `#!` but how it is in my answer.

Comment: nvm i got it, so i would simply just put that command right under #!/bin/bash without the #!. Thanks

Comment: That's right. Basically as early as possible in order to catch it early. Technically, it could still fail if you managed to send SIGINT before the trap line but not so easy to do ;-)

Comment: Wouldn't it be possible to use the builtin -onintr - to just ignore all interrupts and add an if condition for exiting?

Comment: @TinyTox01 onintr is not available in bash. If I am not wrong, it's only available in tcsh and not in other shells.

Comment: @BlueMoon : Tis very possible, I have personally never used it, just stumbled upon it while doing random stuff and therefore asked the question ;) - Am n00b tbh..

Comment: @TinyTox01 np :) You can of course use it if you are using tcsh. Otherwise, `trap` is the way as it's available in most shells.